# Strange behavior when setting rails version in environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails 2.3.4 and rails 2.3.14 gems in my gem directory.  Create a project

```
rails _2.3.4_ foo
```

Replace the line:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

with

```
if true
  RAILS_GEM_VERSION  = '2.3.4'
else
  RAILS_GEM_VERSION = "2.3.14"
end
```

Now when I run the console, I get:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.14)
```

but if type in:

```
>> Rails.version
=> "2.3.4"
```

However, now I just add a comment:

```
if true
  RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4'
  # comment
else
  RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.14'
end
```

and I launch the console, and get:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
Rails version = 2.3.4
```

Note that now it points to 2.3.4 in the "loading" line.  Seems really bizarre to me that a comment will affect this.

Answer (score 0):

The  rails bootstrap code that determines which version of rails to use doesn't actually execute  your environment.rb - it reads in that file and tries to extract what you set `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` to. That code is easily confused by conditionals and so on.

If you want precise control over what versions of gems are used I'd recommend using bundler.